# Add arrays to Realm with swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

I'm new in Realm and I tried to add an Array as I did with strings and I ended up with some errors. So after a little search I found out a solution:

```
class Sensors : Object {


    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var message = ""

    var topic: [String] {
        get {
            return _backingNickNames.map { $0.stringValue }
        }
        set {
            _backingNickNames.removeAll()
            _backingNickNames.append(objectsIn: newValue.map({ RealmString(value: [$0]) }))
        }
    }
    let _backingNickNames = List<RealmString>()

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["topic"]
    }




}

class RealmString: Object {
    dynamic var stringValue = ""
}
```

This is working very good, now I want to add another array inside this class.
If someone knows any other ways to add arrays with realm please share it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem of using List?

Comment: None as i said i'm new and i don't all of my choices

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As a general rule it's way more efficient to use the one-to-many relationships provided by Realm instead of trying to emulate them by using arrays (Realm's collections are lazy, the objects contained are instantiated only when needed as opposed to plain Swift arrays).

In your case, if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you want to add `[RealmString]` Swift arrays to the `_backingNickNames` list.

Why not use the `append(objectsIn:)` method of Realm's `List` class (see [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift4List6appenduRd__s8SequencexzWd__8Iterator7Element_rFT9objectsInqd___T_)), like this:

```
// Dog model
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var owner: Person?
}

// Person model
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var birthdate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)

    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

let jim = Person()

let dog1 = Dog()
let dog2 = Dog()

// here is where the magic happens
jim.dogs.append(objectsIn: [dog1, dog2])
```

If you want to do the opposite (convert from a List to an Array) just do :

```
let dogsArray = Array(jim.dogs)
```

• • • • • • • •

Back to your [own posted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40322996/554203), you could easily refactor the model to accommodate this. Each `Sensor` object could have several `Topic` and several `Message` objects attached.

Just ditch the `message` and `topic` computed properties and rename `topicV` and `messageV` to `topics` and `messages` respectively. Also rename `RealmString` to `Topic` and `RealmString1` to `Message`.

Now, you could easily iterate through the, say, topics attached to a sensor like this :

```
for topic in sensor1.topics { ... }
```

Or if you want to attach a message to a sensor you could do something like this (don't forget to [properly add](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#adding-objects) the newly created object to the DB first):

```
let message1 = Message()
message1.stringValue = "Some text"

sensor2.messages.append(message1)
```

So, no need to use intermediary Swift Arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will check and see if this is what I want

Comment: @mikevorisis : Just curious if this is helping you in any way.

Comment: Actually after a little search and testing I finally understood how this is working and I find your way easier than mine so I will mark your question as the best answer! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

After testing I managed to add another array like that:

```
class Sensors : Object {


    dynamic var type = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var badge = 0

    var topic: [String] {
        get {
            return topicV.map { $0.stringValue }
        }
        set {
            topicV.removeAll()
            topicV.append(objectsIn: newValue.map({ RealmString(value: [$0]) }))
        }
    }

    var message: [String] {
        get {
            return messageV.map { $0.stringValue1 }
        }
        set {
            messageV.removeAll()
            messageV.append(objectsIn: newValue.map({ RealmString1(value: [$0]) }))
        }
    }





    let topicV = List<RealmString>()
    let messageV = List<RealmString1>()

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["topic", "message"]
    }




}

class RealmString: Object {
    dynamic var stringValue = ""
}

class RealmString1: Object {
    dynamic var stringValue1 = ""
}
```

Comment: Mike, it's not very clear why you convert back and forth between Realm Lists and Swift Arrays ? It's very inefficient and adds unnecessary complexity to your code.

Comment: I couldn't understand how can I use the other ways

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a possible way to properly refactor your code in order to take advantage of using full Realm objects and relationships in your model.

Answer (score 0):

What bogdanf has said, and the way you've implemented it are both correct.

Basic value types aside, Realm can only store references to singular Realm `Object` objects, as well as arrays of `Object`s using the `List` type. As such, if you want to save an array of types, it's necessary to encapsulate any basic types you want to save (like a `String` here) in a convenience Realm `Object`.

Like bogdanf said, it's not recommended to convert Realm `List`s to standard Swift arrays and back again, since you lose the advantages of Realm's lazy-loading features (which can cause both performance and memory issues), but memory issues can at least be mitigated by enclosing the code copying data out of Realm in an `@autoreleasepool` block.

```
class MyObject: Object {
    dynamic var childObject: MyObject?
    let objectList = List<MyObject>()
}
```

So in review, it's best practice to work directly with Realm `List` objects whenever possible, and to use `@autoreleasepool` any time you do actually want to loop through every child object in a Realm. :)